# Low performance in 'merge' Colored and Binary image Opencv Python

Tags: python, performance, opencv, numpy, slice

I have a problem to deal with two opencv images in python. I have a color image and I'm using the function **BackgroundSubtractorMOG** that return a binary image. My intention is replace each pixel with 0 in the colored image in a efficient way. The classical approach with **for** isn't helping with that. Can someone help me with tips? Thanks.

**Update**:

```
video = VideoCapture(0)
while True:
  frame = video.read()[1]
  bgs = BackgroundSubtractorMOG().apply()
  for i in range(h):
    for j in range(w):
      if not bgs[i][j]:
        frame[i][j] = (0,0,0)
  imshow('BG Subtracted', frame)
```

I know numpy but I dont have knowledge enough to apply some function in that problem.

Comment: Can you show your code? "The classical approach with for" -- that's a terrible idea especially in an interpreted language. You have numpy and opencv available -- leverage those libraries to avoid the overhead.

Comment: Yeah, no need for those loops. One option is [`cv2.bitwise_and`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and). Just AND `frame` with itself, using `bgs` as a mask.
 [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is another option.